# Favicon missing in headless puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, favicon

I'm writing a simple script to just check if all the resources load correctly (i check status codes of the responses). I've decided to use puppeteer for this and i wrote

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    page.on("response", (res) => {
        const url = res.url(), status=res.status();
        // my functionality goes here
        if (url.includes("favicon")) console.log(status, url); // not logging in headless
    });
    await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

the issue is that if i run my application in headless mode the favicon is missing from the responses, i assume it has something to do with puppeteer not loading a favicon in headless. Any built in functionality or workarounds?

From the lack of a better solution right now I'm evaluating favicons url and manually visiting it

```
async function checkFavicon(page){
    const iconUrl = await page.$eval("link[rel*='icon']", ({href}) => href);
    await page.goto(iconUrl);
    await page.goBack();
}
```